# Getting CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized error while iterating Query Result

Tags: java, sharepoint, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am able to successfully establish a connection between my java based app and SharePoint 2013 using CMIS. Everything works fine. I am running a CMIS Query. The first time the session is created and I run the query it works fine.

But when I run the same query second time using the already created session, it gives me "Unauthorized" error. I have also verified the same using a standalone Java program . Everytime I create a fresh session and run the query. Then it works.

I am getting this exception randomly.

Hope someone could help me solving this. Thanks!

Exception trace :Exception trace : (At the line when I try to perform any kind of operation on query result (even if I try to get the total number of items in query result))

org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:460)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:629)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.DiscoveryServiceImpl.query(DiscoveryServiceImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl$3.fetchPage(SessionImpl.java:600)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:132)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.CollectionIterator.hasNext(CollectionIterator.java:48)

Comment: It actually throws a CmisRuntime Exception when we try to iterate/manipulate the query result , but shows 'unauthorized' in stack trace

Comment: Do you authenticate with NTLM? If so, that would explain this behavior.

Comment: I've ran into the same problem and adding my experiences. My setup is the same (sharepoint+apache chemistry) and the authorization exception is not random - it comes after a successful query. This is reproducable in cmis workbench,  by using NTLM authorization and any two queries - the first finishes succesfully the second one throws unauthorized error. With standard authorization it seems to work okay but when using the same config in apache-chemistry it fails in code.

Answer (score 0):

May be the session is getting expired. Check the session time out. Try re-creating the session when you receive the exception

Comment: On recreating the session, it works fine. But actually that is the problem. I dont want to create a new session everytime, instead want to use the existing one. I have tried with increasing the session time out. But didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the query that you are trying and the exception stack trace

Comment: Query : "SELECT * FROM cmis:document AS C WHERE C.myobjectId >= 1 AND C.cmis:creationDate >= TIMESTAMP '2016-04-25T00:00:00.000Z' AND C.cmis:creationDate <= TIMESTAMP '2016-05-24T23:59:59.999Z'     ORDER BY cmis:name ASC "

(myobjectId is my custom property)

Comment: Added exception trace to the question above